# How do you make a progress bar start moving when you click a button in html

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a progress bar start moving when you click a button in only HTML. How would I do this? Is this impossible? I just started coding with HTML (literally today), and I need some help with this.

Here's what I have right now:

```
<input type="image" src="Button.png" name="saveForm" style = "position:absolute; left:480px; top:400px" />
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a progress bar simply through Bootstrap.

Add this to your HTML code:

```html
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
        <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Declare this in the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Declare this in the last part of the body:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! But for me the progress bar does not move. I don't really know why but if it helps i'm using a notepad.